# android and odbc

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse, odbc

I want to connect odbc connection for oracle 11g database to my android application. Here in my program I want to store two strings to oracle database.  My table name is `name1`. After run the program when I open table the values could not be stored.

```
    package com.odbc;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class OdbcdemoActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            try
            {
        String first="kumar";
        String last="vijay";
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student","system","water");
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into student values(?,?)");
        pst.setString(1,first);
        pst.setString(2,last);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Table name is `name1` but you are inserting data into `student`?

try the following:

```
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student","system","water");
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into name1 (colname1, colname2) values(?,?)");
    pst.setString(1,first);
    pst.setString(2,last);
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

Hope this helps